# Reading two column data from a text file and plot using tikz package

Tags: matplotlib, latex, pdflatex, tikz

I want to export my data in two columns (x and y) and plot them using tikz package in LaTeX. Is there a way to it from a large number of rows? A code snippet would be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `pgfplots` package. Here a simple example:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

% The content of the data file "data.dat".
% Delete this block if you have your data in an external file.
\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
x y
0 0.2
1 3.3
2 1.5
3 1.1
4 2.5
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
      \addplot table {data.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]